# Import/export data from SQL Server by code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Is there a way to recall import/export utilities of SQL Server programmatically.
In my web-app I'd like to import/export data from some database tables to CSV and viceversa simply using SQL Server tools. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run BCP commands from your web applications which can be used to to import the data from sql server table to a csv file and then export the data from csv to table .

To export the data from sql table to a text file

```
    BCP Database.TableName out "Location of the text file " -c -S ServerName -T
```

To load the data from flat file to a table

```
    BCP Database.TableName in "Location of the text file " -c -S ServerName -T
```

Comment: How can I run these commands? Like any other **"SELECT"** or **"UPDATE"** statement? Note I'm using Linq to SQL...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it using Linq but u can execute the above  commands just like you run a stored proc For example string sql; sql="BCP Statement" Exec master..xp_cmdshell sql

Answer (score 0):

Well since your already using .net you can just create a connection string, parse your csv file and then insert rows in your tables,  or use may other c# classes. If you really would like to call an external *.exe using c# you can do the following:

```
Process pLight = new Process();
            // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
            pLight.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pLight.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            pLight.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


            pLight.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\path\to\light.exe";

            pLight.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i -d -ext ";
            pLight.Start();
            // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
            // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
            // p.WaitForExit();
            // Read the output stream first and then wait.
            string lightoutput = pLight.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            pLight.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I'm using Linq to SQL, so is not so easy to import values from CSV files to objects... Can you suggest me some better approach?

Comment: you might want to look at executing a stored procedure in LinqToSQL with a filepath to the csv file? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx